# Creating natural hierarchical order using recursive SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table holding categories with an inner parent child relationship.

The table looks like this:

```
ID | ParentID | OrderID
---+----------+---------
1  | Null     | 1
2  | Null     | 2
3  | 2        | 1
4  | 1        | 1
```

`OrderID` is the order inside the current level.

I want to create a recursive SQL query to create the natural order of the table.

Meaning the output will be something like:

```
ID   |  Order
-----+-------
1    | 100
4    | 101
2    | 200
3    | 201
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the correct or apt input and output sample by seeing the above input n desired o/p wont help at all its incomplete

Comment: Question may be much clear.please provide understandable details.Edit your question

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you mean by "natural order", but the following query generates the results you want for this data:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, NULL, 1), (2, NULL, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 1, 1)) v(ID, ParentID, OrderID)
     )
select t.*,
       (100 * coalesce(tp.orderid, t.orderid) + (case when t.parentid is null then 0 else 1 end)) as natural_order
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.parentid = tp.id
order by natural_order;
```